# Resteasy migration from JBoss 7.1.1 to Wildfly 9.0 special tasks?

Tags: jboss, migration, wildfly, resteasy, noclassdeffounderror

After ensuring that all the libraries (only newer) seemed to exist on Wildfly 9, and checking the RestEasy migration page, I tried to deploy an app that works find on AS 7.1.1 (uses Resteasy 2.3.2) to WF9 (Resteasy 3.0.11) but it was unable to deploy due to this error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/core/ResourceMethod
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod from [Module \\\"deployment.CodecMapper.war:main\\\" from Service Module Loader]\"}}"
```

I jarfinded the class and looked in the catalog of `resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.11-Final.jar` but didn't find it (it *was* in the 2.3.2 version).  Is it in a new jar or failed dependency? Or is this a migration issue I'll need to address in my code (even though it's not listed as one on the [Resteasy migration page](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.11.Final/userguide/html/Migration_from_older_versions.html))?

I have also reviewed the [Wildfly migration page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+WildFly) specific to Resteasy, but I don't see any changes required.

Comment: What is it you're using that class for? Maybe there's something different that can be done.

Comment: I don't think I'm using it - maybe Spring is?  I'm going to recompile the app with the libs current to Wildfly on my classpath to see what happens.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).